# Testing Accuracy is less than half of Trainings Accuracy, and manual testing result is way off

Tags: python, pytorch

Firstly I have to admit that I am total beginner of PyTorch and CNN image classification.

I am making an app to classify cat breeds.

The image sets I gathered have around 300-500 per breed, with a total of 62 breeds, plus one other set which represents non-cats which contains 600 samples. I have split the samples into training and testing respectively at 4:1 ratio.

The training results are quite disappointing. The training accuracy can reach as much as 90% but the testing results are only 39%.

Here are the hyperparameters:

LR is 0.1, momentum is 0.1, and batch_size is 128, wideresnet is using 40 layers of widen factor of 10.

Please see the source code at:

https://github.com/silver-xu/wideresnet-trial

I have searched all over the internet and pretty much 90% of the articles are about pre-compiled datasets like cifar or MNIST. As a result lots of the codes which I found only is optimised for one type of dataset only.

Thanks for all the help! Critics are also Welcome!

Here is training output for Epoch 5:

```
Epoch: [5][0/170]       Time 0.237 (0.237)      Loss 3.3054 (3.3054)    Prec@1 13.281 (13.281)
Epoch: [5][10/170]      Time 0.229 (0.228)      Loss 3.2665 (3.3118)    Prec@1 14.844 (13.920)
Epoch: [5][20/170]      Time 0.227 (0.227)      Loss 3.0962 (3.2856)    Prec@1 17.969 (14.695)
Epoch: [5][30/170]      Time 0.228 (0.227)      Loss 3.3670 (3.2853)    Prec@1 10.938 (14.844)
Epoch: [5][40/170]      Time 0.229 (0.227)      Loss 3.3259 (3.2917)    Prec@1 15.625 (15.282)
Epoch: [5][50/170]      Time 0.228 (0.227)      Loss 3.2016 (3.2931)    Prec@1 14.844 (14.859)
Epoch: [5][60/170]      Time 0.227 (0.227)      Loss 3.3739 (3.3071)    Prec@1 11.719 (14.677)
Epoch: [5][70/170]      Time 0.227 (0.227)      Loss 3.4417 (3.3042)    Prec@1 15.625 (14.833)
Epoch: [5][80/170]      Time 0.226 (0.227)      Loss 3.2507 (3.2996)    Prec@1 10.938 (14.911)
Epoch: [5][90/170]      Time 0.224 (0.227)      Loss 3.2627 (3.2978)    Prec@1 14.844 (15.093)
Epoch: [5][100/170]     Time 0.226 (0.227)      Loss 3.3668 (3.2946)    Prec@1 14.062 (15.060)
Epoch: [5][110/170]     Time 0.225 (0.227)      Loss 3.2839 (3.2915)    Prec@1 10.156 (14.921)
Epoch: [5][120/170]     Time 0.227 (0.227)      Loss 3.3308 (3.2906)    Prec@1 11.719 (14.837)
Epoch: [5][130/170]     Time 0.224 (0.227)      Loss 3.1656 (3.2885)    Prec@1 21.875 (14.909)
Epoch: [5][140/170]     Time 0.226 (0.227)      Loss 3.2521 (3.2851)    Prec@1 20.312 (14.966)
Epoch: [5][150/170]     Time 0.227 (0.227)      Loss 3.1261 (3.2825)    Prec@1 14.844 (14.989)
Epoch: [5][160/170]     Time 0.227 (0.227)      Loss 3.4400 (3.2802)    Prec@1 10.938 (15.018)
Test: [0/43]    Time 0.262 (0.262)      Loss 3.6978 (3.6978)    Prec@1 8.594 (8.594)
Test: [10/43]   Time 0.074 (0.091)      Loss 3.3584 (3.3736)    Prec@1 17.188 (13.139)
Test: [20/43]   Time 0.074 (0.083)      Loss 3.3834 (3.4058)    Prec@1 12.500 (12.537)
Test: [30/43]   Time 0.074 (0.080)      Loss 3.4457 (3.3994)    Prec@1 14.844 (12.802)
Test: [40/43]   Time 0.074 (0.079)      Loss 3.2851 (3.3946)    Prec@1 16.406 (13.281)
 * Prec@1 13.130
```

Comment: Have you trained with a validation set? How does the validation loss compare to the training loss?

Comment: Great! It sounds like you may be overfitting and I would look for early divergence in validation loss (e.g. in epoch < 5) as another indicator of overfitting.

Comment: Here you go. Greatly appreciated for your help.

Comment: You don't appear to be training with a validation set, see this discussion for some basic approaches to train, validation, test patterns in pytorch https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1106

Comment: @Charles Landau I've done what you commented above. The result improved to around 60%. Is there anything I can improve further?

Comment: More data, data augmentation, hyperparameter tuning, taller or wider net, et cetera.